# Change view of feed item

Tags: email, case, feeditem, casefeed

I have Email action in feed section on Case object. When I send an email i have a post below this action and the preview ( before collapse ) is showing first words of email body. Can i change it to show in preview the email subject?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. I think you're question is missing the attachments. So can you please help to edit the question again and add the relevant details for this question?